# Fetching a game boy ROM image

Tags: c, console, emulation, rom, gameboy

i've started to develop a very simple emulator for game boy in C, i've already studied hoe work the cpu of the Z80 and the relative OpCodes but there is a question in my mind that i never found answer. 
When i open the ROM image using 
fopen(filename,"rb")
how can get the instructions to emulate? I've tried to do:
`fp = fopen(filename,"rb");`
`fread(buf,sizeof(buf),1,fp);`but i don't know how is structured the ROM of Game Boy.. someone can explain me how fetch the instruction from the ROM and their structure?

Comment: https://fms.komkon.org/GameBoy/Tech/Software.html

Comment: Thanks for the docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartridge ROM execution always starts at offset 0x100. When writing an emulator you have two ways to implement this:

1. Execute real gameboy boot ROM, which will finish its execution by jumping to 0x100 in the cartridge ROM
2. Fill all the registers with values yourself. After boot ROM is finished registers for CPU and various other devices are left with specific values. You can set them manually and start executing cartridge ROM from 0x100 yourself. That way you don't even need boot ROM. You can find the values in Gameboy CPU Manual.

Comment: Thank you it's worked :)

Comment: If you chose the second route, it's very important to set all the registers to their respective values. Certain games depend on register values to be in specific values on startup.

Comment: i've fetched the first data in the ROM (language code,name,..) an it worked, when i've started to fetch the opcodes but here there are some problems.. he retrieve me a different hex value that is not the opcodes of that address...     char op[16];
  for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
        op[i] = info_header[FIRST];
   } where FIRST is the address where is stored the first instruction